# Uploading Google extension to Microsoft Edge Add-on Store - _MACOSX error

Tags: microsoft-edge

I'm using a mac to upload my extension (which can upload fine to the google chrome extension store)

Is the Microsoft Edge store the same? Should I do anything differently?

I just tried to upload the exact zip file and I'm getting these errors.

Sorry in advance, this is probably a noob question. I have zero experience with the microsoft edge store so I'm not even sure if they allow/make possible to upload from mac? (assuming this from every error containing _MACOSX error)

[image: Error Image]

Here's the error in text format

```
The following checks failed:
Package acceptance validation error: Files or directories outside directory that contains manifest.json chromium are not allowed: __MACOSX, __MACOSX\._chromium, __MACOSX\chromium, __MACOSX\chromium\._.DS_Store, __MACOSX\chromium\._background.js, __MACOSX\chromium\._geo.js, __MACOSX\chromium\._index.html, __MACOSX\chromium\._main.js, __MACOSX\chromium\._manifest.json, __MACOSX\chromium\._popup.html, __MACOSX\chromium\._popup.js, __MACOSX\chromium\AutoStuff, __MACOSX\chromium\css, __MACOSX\chromium\img, __MACOSX\chromium\js, __MACOSX\chromium\_locales, __MACOSX\chromium\AutoStuff\._insert-auto-message.js, __MACOSX\chromium\AutoStuff\._shared-basic.js, __MACOSX\chromium\AutoStuff\._shared-website.js, __MACOSX\chromium\css\._.DS_Store, __MACOSX\chromium\css\._jquery.toast.min.css, __MACOSX\chromium\css\._popup.css, __MACOSX\chromium\css\._style.css, __MACOSX\chromium\img\._.DS_Store, __MACOSX\chromium\img\._icon-128.png, __MACOSX\chromium\img\._icon-1280x800.png, __MACOSX\chromium\img\._icon-16.png, __MACOSX\chromium\img\._logo.png, __MACOSX\chromium\js\._jquery-3.4.1.min.js, __MACOSX\chromium\js\._jquery.toast.min.js, __MACOSX\chromium\_locales\._.DS_Store
```

Edit: I wonder, do I need to format the zip file differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to search for the error `your package failed certification. make corrections and certify again.`

I found that other people had a [similar issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/edge-developer/issues/407) before. I suggest you try to reupload the package. See if it uploads successfully. If the issue persists then there may be some other issue with the package or extension.

You said you are trying to upload the exact same zip file to the MS store. You may need to  [port your existing Chromium extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/developer-guide/port-chrome-extension) to Microsoft Edge

You can refer to this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/publish/publish-extension) may help you to know the process to publish the Edge extension to the MS store.

Comment: Awesome! thanks so much for the info. I'll give it a try and if it works I'll accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and got over it by using the shell to zip it:

```sh
# remove MacOS' .DS_Store file
rm ./my-edge-extension-folder/.DS_Store

# zip the extension
zip -r my-edge-extension.zip ./my-edge-extension-folder
```